# Symbols disappear when exporting map in Arcgis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, legend, color, jpg

I'm trying to export map using ArcGIS. 
Here's how the map looks in the layout view in Arc, and that is how i would like to keep it :
[image]

And this is how the map looks after exporting it as JPEG:
[image]

Can some one advise me please why the symbols are faded on the Baringo map and totally disappeared on the Kitui map, also why the colors, legend, and the map in general is faded?

I have tried PDF, JPEG, and PNG all give this same result. Also the symbols of the fieldwork sites on the Kitui map is not showing at all when exporting to any format !!

Comment: If you export the same map to PDF as a test do you see the same issue? JPG is a lossy format so what parameters did you use when exporting it?

Comment: I have tried PDF, JPEG, and PNG all give this same result. Where can i adjust parameters for JPEG?

Comment: I should add also that the symbols of the fieldwork sites on the Kitui map is not showing at all when exporting to any format !!

Comment: What happens when you eliminate a few layers from your map, so that you can focus on resolving why you are experiencing just one of the several symptoms that you are reporting?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications because potential answerers do not always have enough volunteered time to read the comments.

Comment: Done. i think the problem with just the Kitui map for now, the fieldwork symbol is not showing at all still when exporting to any format. I think it is something with the data frame itself, but i can't figure it out

Comment: If you are trying to focus on just "the fieldwork symbol is not showing at all" then I would not expect to see anything else displayed in ArcMap or the exported JPG.

Comment: Sorry, i did not get you !. It is important to make both maps identical....

Comment: To do that I think it is best to tackle one issue at a time in test maps that are a copy of your original but with most layout elements removed.

Answer (score 2):

in PDF export window in "options" section select "format" tab and then check "convert marker symbols as polygon" and export

Comment: Four years later, this comment is exactly what I needed for a similar situation. Thanks!